# Objective C - Hex values in xml attribute

Tags: objective-c, xml, hex

I need to write an attribute value from NSString in the format of : `&#x00D;` i.e. hex value D. The problem is that the output in the xml is `&amp;x00D;`, How do I correct this?

Comment: first you should convert the hex value to a unicode character. the output is exactly what you wrote with the `&amp;` because the `&` is an escape character in the XML.

Comment: How exactly are you writing this attribute?

Comment: @holex Writing as a character instead of hex as you suggested with formatter %C solved the problem thx